# How does a non deterministic turing machine work?

Tags: theory, complexity-theory, turing-machines

I understand they aren't real and they seem to branch computation whenever there are 2 options, instead of picking one. But, for example, if I say this:

"Non deterministically guess a bijection p of vertices from Graph G to Graph H" (context here is Graph Isomorphism)

What is that supposed to mean? I understand the bijection, but it says "non deterministically guess". If it's guessing, how is that an algorithmic approach? How can it guarantee it's going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's different ways to picture one.  One I find useful is the oracle model.  Did you ever see the Far Side cartoon where a derivation on the blackboard has "Here a miracle occurs" as one of the intermediate steps?  In this version of a NDTM, when you need to choose something, the oracle writes the correct version on the right part of the tape.  (This is taken from Garey and Johnson, *Computers and Intractability*, their classic book on NP-complete problems.)  You aren't allowed to assume you've got the right one, though, and there may not be a correct one.

Therefore, when you non-deterministically guess a bijection, you're getting the correct bijection for your purposes, provided one exists.

It isn't a good basis for an algorithm, since the complexity of implementing a non-deterministic Turing machine is basically exponential in the nondeterministic states, and the algorithmic equivalent of the nondeterministic guess is to try every possible bijection.

From a theoretical point of view, I'd translate it as "If there is a bijection such that....".  From an algorithmic point of view, find another book, or another chapter of the same book, since that approach is useless for even moderately large graphs.

Answer (score 2):

They don't, they just sort of illustrate a point. Basically what they do is guess an answer, and check if it's right(deterministically). It's not the guessing the answer part that's important though, it's checking that the answer is right. It's just like saying given an arbitrary solution, is it correct? So for example there are problems that take exponential time to compute, and some of their answers can be checked in polynomial time, but some can't. So what the non-deterministic TM does is it divides those two, the ones that can be checked quickly from the ones that can't. And then this brings up the bigger question, if one group of questions solutions can be verified much quicker than another, can their solutions also be generated quicker? This question hasn't been answered, yet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what is meant is "non deterministically choose a solution" and then test that the solution is true. Since all possible choices (guesses) are tested, the solution is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

A physical implementation of the non-deterministic Turing machine is the DNA computer.  For example, here's an outline of how to solve the traveling salesman problem in DNA:

1. Get/make a bunch of DNA sequences, each with length proportional to the cost of an edge in your graph and sticky ends with sequences uniquely identifying one of the vertices that the edge connects.
2. Mix them together, with DNA ligase in a big beaker.  They'll anneal to each other in sequences that represent every possible path through the graph (ok, not the really long ones).
3. Remove all the sequences that are missing at least one vertex.  To do this, sequentially select for each vertex using hybridization.  For example, if "ACGTACA" encodes vertex 1, select for sequences that bind to "TGTACGA".  Then repeat this selection for every other vertex.
4. Sort the remaining sequences by size using gel electrophoresis.  Then sequence the shortest one.  The sequence encodes the shortest path through your graph.

Comment: And remember that, for large problems, you need a really, really big beaker.  Possibly one that won't fit in the galaxy.  These problems get bigger real fast.